# Upload existing image version so it becomes its own "base" image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

How can an existing image version, say thumb_xyz.jpg, be reuploaded through Carrierwave so the thumbnail becomes its own "base" image?

I've tried messing with store! uploader, but I can't get it to work...

```
uploader.ImageUploader.new
uploader.store!(image_url(:thumb))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one solution you can tweak and modify to fit your needs! It results in the original parent image with its own crop version, as well as an entirely separate base image of what was cropped. The parent image crop version that is typically used and referenced in Carrierwave serves as a placeholder of sorts, as a means to generate a new base image. So in practice, it will constantly be changing with each and every crop.

If an uploader is mounted onto the model class (as was the case here), the work needs to be done through the associated controller, not in the uploader or model class. This is VERY IMPORTANT.

In this instance, since the goal was to selectively pull out and upload an existing image version and since the cropping itself takes place as part of the controller's update action, the code additions were made there. One of the crucial things to understand was how the file crop file itself is located: `@image.image.versions[:crop]`. With that knowledge, it's then only a matter of passing it through as a parameter.

```
images_controller.rb
...
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @image.update(image_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @image, notice: 'Image was successfully updated.'}
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @image }

      #### HERE IS THE SOLUTION ###
      @crop_image = current_user.images.build(image: @image.image.versions[:crop])
      if @crop_image.save
        format.html { redirect_to @crop_image, notice: 'Crop image successfully created.'}
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @crop_image }
      else
        format.html { render :new, notice: 'Crop image could not be saved for some reason...'}
    end
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @image.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end